# How to empty this panel and add new panels

Tags: java, swing

I have one main `JPanel` container and three JPanels inside. How to empty this panel and add new panels? I tried with `remove(Component)` but it doesn't work. Can anybody give me advice?

Comment: do you validate and/or repaint after removing component in your JPanel?

Comment: Please also note that some `LayoutManager`s don't allow you to remove components from the panel they manage.

Answer (score 3):

This will do it. The trick is to call revalidate.

```
mainPanel = ...

mainPanel.removeAll();
mainPanel.add(newPanel1);
mainPanel.add(newPanel2);
mainPanel.add(newPanel3);
mainPanel.revalidate();
```

But really, consider using CardLayout, if you want to change what appears in a JPanel.

Comment: In addition to revalidate(), you may also want to call `pack()` on the container (`JDialog` or `JFrame`) in order to have the right size.

Answer (score 2):

Here in this [link](http://www.hunter4dev.com/2010/01/adding-removing-and-changing-components.html) i found a simple tutorial on how to add and remove elements from panels. 
The other panels inside your main panel, are also elements, so the same principle applies to them.

A good practices when adding something new in the panel is not just to use the method add():
we might also want to use **revalidate()** and **repaint()** They should be called when some event occurs(button clicked or similar...)

Also i want to mention that in the tutorial remove() i being used to remove elements, you are doing it corretly. Maybe calling again **revalidate()** and **repaint()** for the other panels make the removed panel dissapear from the GUI(The object is deleted just the GUI is not refreshed)

Note: I suppose that the elements of your inner panels are visible = true. If some of the inner elements struggle to render try to call also **revalidate()** and **repaint()** at them. 
I think this way should work.

Answer (score 2):

@ Harry Joy

if you added or removed (already visible container) then you have to call

`revalidate();
repaint(); // not required in all cases`

@ Damir
if JComponents isn't public (or private) static then you can just call

```
myContainer.removeAll();
myContainer.revalidate();
nyCOntainer.repaint();
```

possible is remove `JComponent`(s) by some parameter(s) with `Component[] a = myContainer.getComponents();` then you could call `if (components[i] instanceof JComboBox) {` ...

Answer (score 1):

Try the other remove method `remove(int index);`

Answer (score 1):

this  works 100%

```
this.panelname.Controls.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem. All I did to resolve the issue was

```
panelName.setVisible(false);
mainPanel.remove(panelName);
```

In my case, panelName is a JPanel which lies inside mainPanel.